# Qt проблема с размерностью widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Столкнулся  с проблемой при работе с анимириванием виджета. Суть в том, что при взятии координат и размерности виджета, он выдает, скорее всего, минимальные размерности виджета. В дизайнере по Х 400, а выдает 0.

Вот код:

```
if(ui->widget_3->isVisible()) {
    int x = ui->widget_3->x();
    size_t width = ui->widget_3->width();
    size_t height = ui->widget_3->height();
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->widget_3,"geometry");
    animation->setDuration (1000);
    animation->setStartValue (QRect(x,0, width, height));
    animation->setEndValue (QRect(x,30, width, height));
    animation->start();
    on_lineEdit_textChanged("");
}
else {
    QSize s =  ui->widget_3->size();
    QRect l = ui->widget_3->geometry();
    int x = 9;
    size_t width = ui->widget_3->width();
    size_t height = ui->widget_3->height();
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->widget_3,"geometry");
    animation->setDuration(1000);
    animation->setStartValue(QRect(x,30,width, height));
    animation->setEndValue(QRect(x,0 ,width,height));
    animation->start();
    on_lineEdit_textChanged(ui->lineEdit->text());
    ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
}
```

[image: в designer]

[image: в debug при считывании размерности]

Comment: Подредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, с добавлением ui формы.

Answer (score 2):

Дело может быть в том что вы пытаетесь получить эти значения в конструкторе. А пока не пройдет конструктор виджет не инициализируется и будет возвращать неправильные координаты и размеры.